# Analytics+Statistics for offline Apps?

Tags: google-analytics, statistics, analytics, offline, universal-analytics

As the title suggests, what I need to do is track various user events - such as clicks, swipes, time spent on a page, etc. - in an various iOs/Android/Windows App.

These Apps are based on responsive HTML/CSS/JS and have a simple OS specific container. All data such as images, videos, etc. are self-contained in the Apps.

Characteristic for these Apps is, that sales staff will use iPads/Surface/Android Tablets to demonstrate features of products, spreadsheets, infomercials, etc. to possible clients. One key requirement of the client is that as soon as the tablet connects to the Internet, these Statistics data is pushed to a central Stats Service (or some sort of DB, etc.)

I was reading a bit about Googles' new *[Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en)* and implemented that in "Website Mode" to the HTML of the App. Supposedly it allows tracking offsite-behavior but in my test it only works as long as I am online.
I'm pretty sure I am not the first wanting to do something like this. What implementations can you recommend? I'd hope to get the Universal Offline-Stats up and running in favor of doing some custom messaging/cookie/flatfile based solution.
PS: the tutorials I have found on the interwebs weren't of too much help. either too complicated, not covering the offline part in depth or using being too blurry about this part...

Maybe I do need the iOs/Android SDKs by design to get that part working? What do I do about Windows Surface if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in Universal Analytics works through the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/) which, at the end of the day, is just HTTP requests to the GA backend. All of the GA tracking libraries out there ([analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) for Web and the [Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) SDKs) are just sugar on top of the Measurement Protocol.

If you want to send data to GA, you're going to need to have network access. And if there's no network access, the requests will have to be queued and sent later. As far as I know, none of the tracking libraries fully support this (they may in the future), so unfortunately you may have to implement offline support yourself if it's a hard requirement.

As for Windows phones, like I said, there's always the Measurement protocol, so you should be able to send hits from any device that supports HTTP (even things like printers and TVs).

**Note:** If you're queuing the hits to be sent later, you'll need to record when they occurred and set the [`&qt`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) (queue time offset) parameter in the Measurement Protocol request, otherwise the hit times will be off.

Comment: Can you specify where to find details or docu on the qt parameter? Not sure if I need a different approach, but with Universal Analytics, I'd just like to fire the ga('send','pageview|event', '/some/url'); I cannot find any examples/docs on such a parameter (neither in regular GA nor un UA docs) :S so as you stated the dates shown are wrong

PS: The online/offline detection is a bitch. After playing around with CORS/navigator.onLine/etc for some time, a script called Offline.js does work most stable and cross-browser for me... (http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/)

Comment: The measurement protocol documentation for the `qt` param is linked in my answer. For analytics.js you can do something like: `ga('send', 'pageview', {page:'/some/url', '&qt': 560});` (**Note**: the ampersand syntax is required to set measurement protocol parameters that aren't yet recognized by analytics.js)

Comment: Okay, I see. And the value is the offset in seconds since the event occured?

Comment: In milliseconds. This is directly from the Measurement Protocol docs: "The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent."